# Question regarding to value/reference type of events

Tags: c#, events, event-handling

On the MSDN, I have found following:

```
public event EventHandler<MyEventArgs> SampleEvent;

public void DemoEvent(string val)
{
// Copy to a temporary variable to be thread-safe.
    EventHandler<MyEventArgs> temp = SampleEvent;
```

Is it reference?
If so I do not   understand its meaning as when SampleEvent became null, so does the temp

```
    if (temp != null)
        temp(this, new MyEventArgs(val));
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is a paranoia thing to do with threading. If *another* thread unsubscribes the last handler *just after* you've checked it for `null`, it could *become* `null` and you'll cause an exception. Since delegates are immutable, capturing a snapshot of the delegate into a variable stops this from happening.

Of course, it does have the *other* side effect that you could (instead) end up raising the event against an object that thinks it already unsubscribed...

But to stress - this is only an issue when multiple threads are subscribing / unsubscribing to the object, which is a: rare, and b: not exactly desirable.

Comment: A nice, yet precise, explanation :o)

Comment: Note that you can *always* end up raising the event against a handler that thinks it's unsubscribed - because it could unsubscribe after you've started executing the delegate but before you've reached the one that unsubscribes itself.

Comment: So the key fact here (to target asker's reasonable question that delegates are of a reference type) is that "delegates are immutable", so this assignment "captur[es] a **snapshot** of the delegate". Right?

Comment: I thougt immutable means that it does not change itself. Do not understand why its the reason for assigning it to variable.

Comment: @Petr - you capture the **current** value of the delegate field. When code subscribes/unsubscribes, it *replaces* this with a *different* reference (which might well be `null`).

Comment: Marc, thank you. But if this reference chances (even to null), it will point to null...so I still did not get the point of it.

Comment: @Petr - imagine we just have `if(SomeEvent!=null) SomeEvent(...)`; sequence of events: Thread A does the `null` check (`if(SomeEvent!=null)`) and finds it *isn't* `null`. Thread B *unsubscribes* and in doing so changes the field to `null`. Thread A gets some more CPU cycles and invokes (`SomeEvent(...)`) on a `null` instance. Kabooooooom!

Comment: Marc, yes, I understand it. But I do not get a point of using variable which holds the reference as you said it changes (as reference does) when original handler changes. So it still can be null..or what am I missing?

Comment: @Petr : once you've obtained the delegate value from the *field* into a *variable*, that *variable* **doesn't** change. The other thread changes the *field*, not your local *variable*. It isolates your thread (that is checking for `null` and invoking the delegate) from other threads (potentially changing the field).

Comment: Marc, I really appreciate your help. However, to me it seems that its value type.
With objects, it would change the variable, right?
Object a=new Object();
object x=a;

Comment: @Petr - No, it is a reference-type, but immutable (think: like string). When you add a reference it **isn't** `theField.Add(newValue)` - but rather it is `theField = Delegate.Combine(theField, newValue)` - i.e. take the old delegate and the new delegate and combine them to create a **new** delegate instance.

Comment: @Petr - and in your example, if you then **reassign** `a` (for example, `a = "abc";`), `x` doesn't notice the change. `x` still points to the original `object`. Same concept.

Comment: Oh, I hope I get it. I have played with it..by practice I learn the best. Only wonder why I cannot find anything about eventhandler being immutable on MSDN.
I understand it the following way: A=B -both objects points to some location in memory. When B is set to null (e.g.), A still points to the previous location and so then A is not equal B.

Answer (score 2):

(From what I read in Essential C# 4.0)

Basically, from this C# code:

```
public class CustomEventArgs: EventArgs {…}
public delegate void CustomEventHandler(object sender, CustomEventArgs a);
public event CustomEventHandler RaiseCustomEvent;
```

the compiler will generate CIL code (loosely) equivalent to the following C# code:

```
public delegate void CustomEventHandler(object sender, CustomEventArgs a);

private CustomEventHandler customEventHandler; // <-- generated by the compiler

public void add_CustomEventHandler(CustomEventHandler handler) {
  System.Delegate.Combine(customEventHandler, handler);
}

public void remove_CustomEventHandler(CustomEventHandler handler) {
  System.Delegate.Remove(customEventHandler, handler);
}

public event CustomEventHandler customEventHandler {
  add { add_customEventHandler(value) }
  remove { remove_customEventHandler(value) }
}
```

When you copy the event, you actually copy the `private CustomEventHandler customEventHandler`. Since delegate is immutable, the copy won't be affected when the original `customEventHandler` is modified. You can try this code to see what I mean:

```
string s1 = "old"; 
string s2 = s1; 
s1 = "new"; // s2 is still "old"
```

Another important characteristic to note about the generated CIL
code is that the CIL equivalent of the `event` keyword remains in the CIL.
In other words, an event is something that the CIL code recognizes
explicitly; it is not just a C# construct. By keeping an equivalent `event`
keyword in the CIL code, all languages and editors are able to provide
special functionality because they can recognize the event as a special
class member.

I guess you were confused mainly because you thought event is a sugar-syntax for a class, right?

Comment: Shouldn't the code in `add_CustomEventHandler` be `customEventHandler = System.Delegate.Combine(customEventHandler, handler);`, and equivalently for `remove_CustomEventHandler`? The point is precisely that the orginal reference is replaced when the event is updated.