# Internal design of event in C#

Tags: c#

Just finished reading Jon Skeet's [article about events and delegates](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter2/Events.aspx) and got a question.

Lets say first in the code I declare an event

```
public event EventHandler MyEvent
```

Then I want to raise it in the code in a manner

```
if (MyEvent != null)
    Myevent(this,EvtArgs.Empty);
```

Jon says that in fact MyEvent looks somehow like this:

```
private EventHandler _myEvent;

public event EventHandler MyEvent
{
    add
    {
        lock (this)
        {
            _myEvent += value;
        }
    }
    remove
    {
        lock (this)
        {
            _myEvent -= value;
        }
    }        
}
```

The question is what really happens when I compare `MyEvent != null` ?
As I understand in fact it compares `_myEvent` to `null`, but I am not sure.

Comment: That is my understanding also, hopefully the great man will come in and enlighten us :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you implement custom add/remove accessors, you won't be able to compare `MyEvent` to null in the first place, because it will *only* be an event - it doesn't have a value as such, only add/remove accessors. You would have to use your *declared* field (`_myEvent` in the sample above) instead.

You can only do the comparison using the event name when you're using *field-like events*, where you end up with (effectively) a field and an event with the same name. (The compiled code doesn't have to actually reuse the event name for the field name, but it has to *look* like it does when you're compiling.)

Note that using this:

```
if (MyEvent != null)
    MyEvent(this,EvtArgs.Empty);
```

isn't thread-safe, as `MyEvent` could become null *between* the check and the invocation. You should use:

```
EventHandler handler = MyEvent;
if (handler != null)
{
    handler(this, EventArgs.Empty);
}
```

Also note that the part about field-like events locking on `this` is now slightly outdated; in C# 4 thread-safety is achieved using a lock-free compare-exchange mechanism.

Comment: That isn't thread safe either. This way you can call a handler of a disposed class.

Comment: @WouterH: Potentially. That race condition is unavoidable though, unless you lock for the duration of the invocation - whereas the race condition in the question *is* avoidable.

Answer (score 1):

When there is no handler subscribed to MyEvent, MyEvent will equal null. So before firing the event, you first check if there is at least one handler subscribed to it.

Answer (score 1):

Internally an event is a set of add/remove methods with a backing field of type MulticastDelegate  You get this field when you are asking for MyEvent outside of the class and compare this instance to null.

See also this post: [How do C# Events work behind the scenes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/213638/how-do-c-sharp-events-work-behind-the-scenes)

**Edit:** Also, as pointed out by Jon already, you don't get a field in case you provide the add/remove methods yourself.

Comment: No, an event is just an add/remove pair. A *field-like event* consists of an event *and* a backing field (of the event type). The code compares the value of that field with null.

Comment: Further clarification - there's no *requirement* for a backing field at all. It's like a property - what you do is up to you, but *typically* there will be a backing field (of the event type, not just bare MulticastDelegate).