# What does the .NET Virtual Machine do when I raise an event?

Tags: .net, events, virtual-machine

What exactly is /technically/ happening when I raise an event in .NET? 
I couldn't answer this question myself via Google.

I don't mean: the event is raised and suddenly some handler is being called, I mean what is happning in between? Are the events somehow stored on an invisible event stack? Are they queued somewhere? How many events can I raise? etc.

I hope someone can shed some light on how the .NET virtual machine processes events.

Comment: This might be a good reference : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/213638/how-do-c-sharp-events-work-behind-the-scenes

Comment: Thanks, this one explains it very well!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Regular .NET events are ***usually*** simply delegate invocations, which are not very much different to regular method invocations. The only subtle difference is that because delegates are multi-cast, it has to unroll the full invocation list of all subscribers, and invoke them in turn. This all happens during the delegate `.Invoke()`. So no, there is no special event stack / queue.

However! Some things on UI technologies (winforms, WPF, etc) *do* use the Windows message loop  - so *in those cases*, yes, there is a logical queue.

Each delegate subscription (i.e. `foo.SomeEvent += this.SomeHandler`) involves two things: a target instance (the `this`) and a target method (`SomeHandler`). When invoked, the delegate simply invokes the method against the specified target. Slightly magic, but not *that* different to regular method invoke.