# Need to understand how events work with delegates in C#

Tags: c#, events, delegates

I cannot understand how delegates work with events in C#.

The form of the syntax is:

public event someNameDelegate someName;

control.someName += new control.someNameDelegate(methodName);

So how does it know what event (like mouse click etc) fires the method.
I'm totally missing how this works.
I understand that the delegate will call methodName but I don't understand for what event.

[Addittional Info]
In the 2 lines above if someName is ContentModified then the code compiles
In the 2 lines above if someName is Banana then the code does not compile.

However ContentModified is nowhere else in the code apart from the 2 line above:

So How does the compiler tell the difference?

Comment: How does what know what fires the method?

Comment: It's unclear what you call "it". Perhaps you miss the part raising event? Assuming you know delegates, have you been [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/213651/1997232) already?

Comment: the event handle need to derive from EventArgs and the delegate should have sign like this : void OnEventHandling(object sender,EventArgs argument)

Comment: Take a look at these tutorials: [Delegates (TutorialsPoint)](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/csharp_delegates.htm) and [Events (TutorialsPoint)](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/csharp_events.htm) and [Delegates (TutorialsTeacher)](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/csharp/csharp-delegates) and [Events (TutorialsTeacher)](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/csharp/csharp-event).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When & why to use delegates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2019402/when-why-to-use-delegates) and [Where do I use delegates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31497/where-do-i-use-delegates)

Comment: What technology do you use (WinForms, WPF, UWP, ASP.NET, GTK...)? You may also find this helpful: [Event Overview (Windows Forms .NET)](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/desktop/winforms/forms/events) and [Event order in Windows Forms](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/desktop/winforms/order-of-events-in-windows-forms)

Comment: @Olivier Rogier in this case it is WPF but in future I could experience the problem in other technologies.

Answer (score 1):

For example, suppose you create a userControl and your control has a button, and when the button text changes, you define an event for it. That is, you see where the button text changes and there you define an event for it.

```
 public event TextChangedEventHandler ItemTextChanged;
 public delegate void TextChangedEventHandler(object Sender);




 private void btnContent_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
      if (ItemTextChanged != null)
      {
           ItemTextChanged(txtbChildBtn);
      }
 }
```

Same example with another name

```
public event ValueChangedEventHandler ItemValueChanged;
public delegate void ValueChangedEventHandler(object Sender);




private void btnContent_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   if (ItemValueChanged != null)
   {
       ItemValueChanged(sender);
   }
}
```

or FucosChanged button

```
 public event FucosEventHandler FucosChanged;
 public delegate void FucosEventHandler(object Sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e);

 private void btnContent_FocusableChanged(object sender, , DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
 {
      if (FucosChanged != null)
      {
           FucosChanged(sender, e);
      }
 }
```

Comment: Yes, but how do you know it is TextChangedEventHandler rather that TextFontChangedEventhandler or some other name. Is there a list of the allowed ones somewhere?

Comment: Ah, I see what I was looking for. It's in the metadata for TextBoxBase 
e.g. public static readonly RoutedEvent TextChangedEvent;

Comment: Using the delegete keyword, you can select any name and create any type of event without any restrictions.

Comment: @meyasm asadi You are correct, but what I was looking for was where I could get what type of events are available. e.g. is there TextSpecialChar event available for textbox. The metadata provides this.